# SPARQL fn:replace thorws error: "syntax error, expected primary expression"

Tags: sparql, tracker, fedora-21

I'm working on a music player app that relies on SPARQL to get information about local tracks, and have been running into some trouble.

I'm running Fedora 21, and the database (Tracker) is queried via grilo (i.e., I write raw SPARQL queries, and grilo uses these queries to talk to the database and sends back any results).

Basically, any time I try to use `REPLACE`, I get the following:

```
Grilo-WARNING : [tracker-source-request] grl-tracker-source-api.c:500: Could not execute sparql query id=1: 1.273: syntax error, expected primary expression
```

When I attempt to use `fn:replace`, I instead get:

```
Grilo-WARNING : [tracker-source-request] grl-tracker-source-api.c:500: Could not execute sparql query id=1: 1.284: syntax error, Unknown function
```

For reference, here's the context in which I'm attempting to use `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    rdf:type(?album)
    tracker:id(?album) AS id
    (
        SELECT
            nmm:artistName(?artist)
        WHERE {
            ?album nmm:albumArtist ?artist
        }
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS artist
    REPLACE(nie:title(?album)^^xsd:string, "hello", "goodbye") AS title
    nie:title(?album) AS album
    [more SPARQL gobbldygook follows]
```

If you want a sense of what the other queries look like, [view the whole file](https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-music/tree/gnomemusic/query.py?id=c635de1ea92461bd6889b18c56e72820f3cac7f0#n128).

The ultimate goal is to use `REPLACE` to strip off punctuation from album/artist names for sorting purposes.

Thanks!

Comment: Not quite sure I understand your full setup, but the query as you have it in your question is not legal standard SPARQL - apart from the fact that there are no `rdf:type` or `tracker:id` functions (though those could perhaps have been added as custom extensions by the SPARQL engine you're using), you are missing opening and closing brackets around various parts in the SELECT clause (basically, every clause element involving `AS` aliasing should be surrounded by brackets).

Comment: `REPLACE` is a function that was added in the 1.1 revision of SPARQL. Perhaps your query engine is not fully compatible with the revised spec?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given us a minimal example to work with, but at least part of your problem is in trying to treat properties as functions, both in the query and in the projection variables.  You don't write something like:

```sql
select rdf:type(?album) where { ... }
```

to select the value of the **rdf:type** property for **?album**.  Instead you do:

```sql
select ?type where { ?album rdf:type ?type }
```

The chunk of code that you've shown us should probably be something like:

```sql
select distinct ?type ?id (?title as ?albumTitle)
where {
  ?album rdf:type ?type ;
         tracker:id ?id ;
         nie:title ?title ;
         nmm:albumArtist ?artist .
}
```

That much would take care of selecting the values.  Now, to replace occurrence of "hello" in the title with "goodbye", you'd do:

```sql
select distinct
  ?type
  ?id
  (replace(?title,"hello","goodbye") as ?albumTitle)
where {
  ?album rdf:type ?type ;
         tracker:id ?id ;
         nie:title ?title ;
         nmm:albumArtist ?artist .
}
```

Now, it is possible that an endpoint supports additional functions.  So, for instance, it's possible that the endpoint has a function **nie:title** that you pass an IRI and get a title out.  If that's the case, you'll still need to use proper SPARQL syntax and either do:

```sql
bind(nie:title(?album) as ?title)
```

in the query or

```sql
select ... (nie:title(?album) as ?title) ... where { ... }
```

in the query.  The parentheses around the **nie:title(…) as ?title** are mandatory.  (Some endpoints might not enforce all the syntax, but it *is* in the specification.)

Answer (score 0):

Tracker doesn't support this yet.

There was recently a patch added to bugzilla to bring this feature in. We should be seeing this in 1.4.0 (stable) or later unstable releases like 1.3.5 perhaps.

The bug for this patch is here:
https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=745917

Comment: The bug is currently RESOLVED FIXED.